# Caffe compiling error with Python 3.6 on Mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, boost, installation, caffe

Alternatively to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45895194/caffe-compiling-error-using-anaconda-python-3-6-on-mac), I also tried to install Caffe with Python 3.6 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 **but without Anaconda**. I followed the [official instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html) to install it.

The problem came when typing `make all`. The terminal threw 8 errors or so, all related to the boost library and the file "shared_ptr.hpp". This is one of those errors:

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.o] Error 1
In file included from src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp:8:
In file included from ./include/caffe/data_transformer.hpp:6:
In file included from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8:
./include/caffe/common.hpp:4:10: fatal error: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

I installed boost via Brew. Here is my **Makefile.config file**. I just want to use the CPU for Caffe.

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
# OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
#           /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := /Applications/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
#       $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python3.6m \
#       $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.6m
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m \
                /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# NCCL acceleration switch (uncomment to build with NCCL)
# https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl (last tested version: v1.2.3-1+cuda8.0)
# USE_NCCL := 1

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

# N.B. both build and distribute dirs are cleared on `make clean`
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

What am I doing wrong? Any clue? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Mac + CMake, but as a workaround you can simply add your Boost include directly to:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
```

In Makefile.config
(You'll probably need to add the boost libraries path to:

```
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib
```

)

Comment: These two lines are already included in the Makefile.config I posted above. I also checked if the Boost library was really in those paths and it was there indeed.

Comment: Can you enable pretty build (Comment ""Q ?= @"" line in Makefile.config) to see the full include path make uses?

Comment: Sure. In addition, I've been playing around with the Makefile.config and now I get a similar error to the one I got using Anaconda. Let me show it in a longer answer below.